# Solve $(\log_5 x)^2 - 3\log_5(x) + 2 = 0$. How to simplify $(\log_ab)^c?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve $(\log_5 x)^2 - 3\log_5(x) + 2 = 0$.

I tried to solve this question but got stuck:

\begin{align}
(\log_5 x)^2 - 3\log_5(x) + 2 &= 0 \\
(\log_5 x)^2 &= \log_5(x^3) - 2 \\
\log_{(\log_5 x)}(\log_5 x)^2 &= \log_{( \log_5 x)}(\log_5(x^3) - \log_5 25) \\
2 &= \log_{(\log_5 x)}\left( \log_5\frac{x^3}{25} \right)
\end{align}

Was my approach wrong? Where do I go from here?

Comment: $\log_5x=t$. This is a quadratic equation. $$(t-1)(t-2)=0$$

Comment: Let $y = \log_5(x).$  Then construct a quadratic equation in $(y)$.  Then solve for $(y)$.  Then convert your solution into a solution for $(x)$.

Comment: Your calculations are correct but you are spinning your wheels without an end plan.  $\log_{\log_a} \log_a K$ is probably a bad idea.  I would suggest taking $5$ to each side of the equation (if solving as quadratic never occurs to us) but that leads us to $x^{\log_5 x} = \frac {x^3}{25}=\frac {x^3}{x^{\log_x 25}} = x^{3-\log_x 25}$ and $\log_5 x= 3 - \log_x 25= 3-2\log_x 5= 3 -\frac 2{\log_5 x}$ which will be just spinning wheels until it occurs to us to replace $u =\log_5 x$ and solving. Eventually it will need to hit us this is just a quadratic.

Comment: As a side note, it is generally difficult to deal with $(\log x)^y$.

Comment: Why @Trebor ? It's $\log x^{\log x^{\dots}}$ with height $y$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Uh, if you consider that as "easy to deal with" then fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a quadratic equation, but instead of variables you have logarithms. You can let $u=\log_5x$ and get

$$u^2-3u+2=0$$

$$(u-2)(u-1)=0$$

from which $\log_5x=1$ and $\log_5x=2$.